# Traveling to Philippines

Tags: romania, philippines, romanian-citizens, philippine-airlines

I am Morrocan resident in Romania as a family member.
I need to travel to Philippines on February for 2 weeks and I would like to know if I can travel with my residence documentation without visa.

Comment: I just want to confirm, you are a Moroccan citizen right? (because you used the tag "romanian-citizen"

Answer (score 1):

(since I am unsure of your citizenship - as far as I understood, you are Moroccan - I am answering for both).

For both Moroccan and Romanian nationals, one can travel to the Philippines visa free for 30 days, provided your passport is valid for at least 6 months beyond your intended period of stay in the Philippines

Source: http://consular.dfa.gov.ph/visainformation